# ActionMailer does not log e-mail body to rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

With `rails s` I can see the entire delivered e-mail in the log output, but using `rails c` and `Notification.the_mail().deliver` I see no more than a long single line showing the headers:

```
 => #<Mail::Message:70159541028200, Multipart: true, Headers: <Date: Fri, 06 Dec 2013 15:43:59 +0100>, <From: TestTitle <x@y.com>>, <Message-ID: <52a1e2af4d5ae_c11c3fcf4a034ec8548da@computer.xxx.local.mail>>, <Subject: TestSubject>, <Mime-Version: 1.0>, <Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="--==_mimepart_52a1e2af4b1c4_c11c3fcf4a034ec854530"; charset=UTF-8>, <Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit>>
```

Where is the body??

`Rails.logger.info` outputs are omitted by `rails c` as well...

How can I get the full log output? I tried all log levels from 0-5...

Answer (score 2):

In the Rails console in the development environment, you will only see the return value logged to stdout as you show above.

If you want to find the message body, you will need to look in the Rails log file, which should be `log/development.log` in your project.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. How can I log everything to STDOUT? `log/development.log` is currently not the place where I need the log.

Comment: I know it's far too late, but maybe it can still help someone. You need to include this line in development.rb / production.rb:

`config.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)`

Answer (score 0):

I know it is not the case of the OP, but I came here from Google and I would like people after me to be sure they don't do the same mistake I did.

In my case was that I forgot to add the `.deliver` call at the end :/

```
# Wrong
Notification.the_mail()

# Right
Notification.the_mail().deliver
```